# CMK vs CMEK in GCP (BigQuery)

Tags: database, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, encryption, google-bigquery

Is there any difference between a Customer managed Key (**CMK**) vs Customer Managed Encryption Key (**CMEK**) in the context of GCPs BigQuery service? Some documentations and security benchmarks are apparently using it interchangeably.

Comment: Do you have reference documentation about the 2? Especially the CMK. Is it the column value encryption feature?

Comment: The correct term in Google Cloud is CMEK. The term CMK is used in AWS to mean KMS Customer Master Key (now deprecated) [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/concepts.html). I think other sources use CMK interchangeably with CMEK but I would need to read their material to know for sure.